# AWS elastic beanstalk Linux 2 with Django application failed to deploy

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am in this strange situation where I could not deploy the same code base to elastic beanstalk Linux 2 server after first time. The first deployment(after intentionally crashed server or new environment) works with no error but if I deploy the same code base again, It would fail at python manage.py migrate command in my .config file.

command 01_migrateddb (`source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput`) failed

I tried to put all my eb container commands in .config into .platform/hooks as .sh scripts, the deployment works, but I would get 502 Bad Gateway error and unable to see my site.

Any insight?

Comment: So what is the server log from the failing `python manage.py migrate` command? Please edit your original question to include that log.

Comment: command 01_migrateddb (source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput) failed